# rainbow table generation software

Tags: gpu

I need a program that will generate WPA-PSK rainbow tables with a GPU. There are many programs that use CPU for generation but not GPU. I need the program to work with 2 GTX 880M gpus.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two:

http://www.cryptohaze.com/gpurainbowtables.php

http://project-rainbowcrack.com/

The first one is a king of password cracking framework, using which you can implement rainbow tables generation with GPU acceleration for your chosen algorithm using "bricks" in C++.

Comment: When I use GRT-gen-cud from crypto haze it says it is missing cutil64.dll

Comment: See http://www.cryptohaze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1188